# Unsupported add/addAll operations for Map<K,V>.keySet()

Tags: java, dictionary, set, keyset, unsupportedoperation

Regarding the [`Map<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true) interface:

Why does `keySet()` return a `Set` that supports the `remove` operation but doesn't support `add()` and `addAll()` operations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Set` returned by `keySet` is backed by the `Map`, so changes to the map are
reflected in the set, and vice-versa. This means that calling `remove` on that `Set` removes the matching `Entry` from the `Map`.

It would make no sense to call `add` or `addAll` on that `Set`, since you can't add key[s] without corresponding value[s] to the `Map`.

Comment: Would it be so unreasonable to default to a null value? Imagine you want a WeakSet by calling WeakHashMap.keySet - sure it's possible with Collections.newSetFromMap, but that's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you are asking for:

you want to retrieve all KEYS of a map (and that set is not a "copy" of the keys; it represents the keys of the map).

And then you ask to add elements to those KEYS. In other words: the "data set" you are looking at has the semantic meaning of keys coming from a map. And you want to increase that "data set" - but without providing the corresponding entries for that map.

Deletion on the other hand is straight forward; deleting a key will also delete the corresponding entry from the map.

Answer (score 2):

It's because each key in the set is linked to a value in the map. Removing a key will remove the associated value, but to add you'll need a value and not just a key.